# LESS - How to use & when, if conditions in less css

Tags: less

I am start using less css few days ago. My understanding is ok about mixins, variables and all. Just want to know about conditions uses in less. If anybody give me some examples, ideas or articles of how its use it would be great! Thanks. Below is the code example, didnt understand how **& when** uses.

```
.box{
  foo: bar;
  & when (1 = 1) {
    baz: qux;
  }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910667/how-to-use-if-statements-in-less could maybe help you

Comment: Thanks @Sergej its helpful