# Implementing Less when condition with child conditions

Tags: html, css, less

I am not sure if I am doing this right. I am wanting to do if statements within the when, but they don't seem to be working, here is an example:

The issue I have is the nested conditions, the main when condition works fine

```
@han_cart_icon: 'fa-shopping-cart';
@han_fa_version: 'v5';

.change_basket_icon() when (@han_cart_icon = fa-shopping-cart) {
  if (@han_fa_version == 'v4'){
    i.ty-icon-moon-commerce,
    .ty-icon-basket {
      font-family: FontAwesome;

      &:before {
        content: "\f07a";
      }
    }
  }
  if(@han_fa_version == 'v5'){
    i.ty-icon-moon-commerce,
    .ty-icon-basket {
      font-family: "Font Awesome\ 5 Free";

      &:before {
        content: "\f07a";
      }
    }
  }
  .small_fixes_mini_cart();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use if statements in LESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910667/how-to-use-if-statements-in-less)

Comment: not the same, my when statement works fine, the issue is with nested conditions that article you suggested does not cover that

Comment: Just put a `when(){}` statement within another `when(){}`. LESS does not support the keyword `if` and it also doesn't understand the `==` symbols.

Comment: I did try that, was something like: .change_user_icon() when (@han_user_icon = fa-user-circle-o) {
 @when (@han_fa_version = v4) {

Answer (score 0):

The Less documentation says you can use [CSS Guards as if statements](http://lesscss.org/features/#css-guards-feature) with the `& when()` feature. With that in mind, I updated your code to support nested "if" statements using this method:

```
@han_cart_icon: 'fa-shopping-cart';
@han_fa_version: 'v5';

// Parent "if" statement
.change_basket_icon() when (@han_cart_icon = 'fa-shopping-cart') {

    // First nested "if" statement
    & when (@han_fa_version = 'v4'){
        i.ty-icon-moon-commerce,
        .ty-icon-basket {
            font-family: FontAwesome;

            &:before {
                content: "\f07a";
            }
        }
    }

    // Second nested "if" statement
    & when (@han_fa_version = 'v5'){
        i.ty-icon-moon-commerce,
        .ty-icon-basket {
            font-family: "Font Awesome\ 5 Free";

            &:before {
                content: "\f07a";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `'fa-shopping-cart'` has to be in quotation marks, and when making comparisons, you must use a simple `=` sign, not two.

Comment: I get LESS parse error: failed at `&amp; when (@han_fa_version = 'v4'){` design/themes/responsive/css/addons/han_font_awesome/styles.less on line 55

Comment: if i remove the single brackets, get no error but its not working with the conditions and adjusting the css

Comment: `&amp;` is not the same as `&`. Are you sure your code looks like mine?

Comment: @James, In addition to the answer: 1. It does not have to be that bloating ([example](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/d2713c9a34d1c91077a47eb9635cd1d6)). 2. One is better to define font name directly instead of indirectly forcing it via `v4`/`v5`/`velse` flags - [example](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/b115e52bb7367ff373e751aeb9d28f8f) (what is the point of having that flags at all? - overengineering police).