# If LESS variable is 1 add CSS to element

Tags: css, less

Im having trouble with I think a pretty simple thing. I need to add CSS to a element if a less variable equals to 1. Its kind of a on/off switch. I tried a few tutorials on guards but i dont think i get it the right way. My code:

```
@switch = 1
#element() when (@switch = 1) {
color: red;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use if statements in LESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910667/how-to-use-if-statements-in-less)

Answer (score 2):

First, you declare a variable using `@switch: <value>;`
Then you drop the `()` from the element and use `& when (@switch = 1)` condition inside the body of the selector.

```
@switch: 1;

#element {
    & when (@switch = 1) {
        color: red;
    }

}
```

Or you could use an inline `if` function like below:

```
#element {
  color: if((@switch = 1), red, blue);
}
```

The later is the same as a ternary operator in any other language, first parameter is the logical operator, second value you want if the condition is true and an else value.

Answer (score 2):

You are defining the variable incorrectly. You need to use the `:` and not `=`.

```
@switch: 1;
  #element when ( @switch = 1) {
     color: red;
}
```

Which compiles to:

```
#element {
  color: red;
}
```

If the condition is met.

Answer (score -2):

Turned out i had an old LESS version. The first solution from this link helped:
https://github.com/less/less-docs/blob/master/content/features/css-guards.md